# How to get JSON with JS and jQuery after requesting user's location

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, global-variables

I am stuck with this one for quiet a bit already. I know that the "building a weather app" question has been asked a few times already but that's not mainly what I am struggling with. 
I am trying to write a script that get's the location of the user / computer and takes those to an external website (openweathermap.org) to get the JSON of the specific location. It works perfectly to this point:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Weather App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,700">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#click").click(function() {
                    if(navigator.geolocation) {
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                            $("#message").text("lat: " + position.coords.latitude + " and long: " + position.coords.longitude);
                        });
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <button id="click" ">Get Location</button>
        </div>  
        <div id = "message">
            Message goes here
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get the `longitude` and `latitude` displayed on my website. But if I change the script to:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#click").click(function() {
            if(navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    $.getJSON("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&lon=" + position.coords.longitude, function(json) {
                        $("#message").html(JSON.stringify(json));
                    });
                });
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

nothing works anymore. I am still insecure with that kind of JS / jQuery usage so here are my questions: 
 1. What is more common: the notation I used ( click handler, $-sign) or the `getElementBy`, `x.innerHTML` coding (I have obviously no clue how those two things are called but I hope what you mean)?
 2. I tried to define the variables `var lat = position.coords.latitude` and `var long = position.coords.longitude` within the `navigator` function (in an earlier version) but it seems I can just use them within that function even tough it's defined outside that function - why?
 3. When I try to insert the link where I want to get the JSON from - there seems to be something terribly wrong. I tried it with `api`, `http://api`, `https://`, `https://api`, `http://www.` but nothing seems to work. In case I don't get the `lat` and `long` right I even tried it with some specific values for that - no success. Why? How to you set up the link properly? Also is there my `appid` in the end missing because if I click the demo link it looks more like: `http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b1b15e88fa7024532541123439c1c50c122a1`

I think that's it for the moment. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks, guys!

Comment: check the console of the browser for errors and see what it says. as for appid, check the documentation: http://openweathermap.org/appid

Comment: that's what I get back, @Jorg: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///filename/weat…thermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=53.594914900000006&lon=11.4551430988899. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: I havent checked the API docs but it looks you are missing the proper header/CORS policy, if it s allowed from this API. The very much prefered solution would be to have your server do the query and send it back to you across ajax.

Comment: @MickeyMahoney so reading the error, and then looking at the url, what does that tell you? I think the demo URL is correctly formatted (includes `http` and includes an `appid`)